# innerText returning is including the tags

Tags: vba, url, tags, innertext

i'm very new to VBA and Webscraping. I'm trying to open a URL which is inside an XML Document.

```
http://research.investors.com/services/AutoSuggest.asmx/GetQuoteResults?q=txn&limit=10
```

InnerText gives me the URL but including `<Url>` and `</Url>`.

```
<Url>http://research.investors.com/stock-quotes/nasdaq-apple-inc-aapl.htm</Url>
```

Thats why i can't open the URL. 
Here is my code:

```
    Sub Macro1()

Dim ie As Object


Set Rng = Range("A3:A6")

Set Row = Range(Rng.Offset(1, 0), Rng.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))

        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        With ie
        .Visible = True
        For Each Row In Rng
        .navigate "research.investors.com/services/AutoSuggest.asmx/GetQuoteResults?q=" & Range("A" & Row.Row).Value & "&limit=10"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Do
        DoEvents
        Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Dim doc As HTMLDocument
        Set doc = ie.document
        While ie.readyState <> 4

        Wend


       .navigate doc.getElementsByTagName("Url")(0).innerText




        Next Row
    End With
    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

I hope someone can point me to what i did wrong.

Thanks a lot, bye
Nightflight

Comment: If it's an XML document you should really parse it as XML, not HTML. "Url" isn't a valid HTML tag (although it does seem to be found by getelementsbytagname), so maybe IE doesn't know how to render the innerhtml...

Comment: note: you have some inconsistency in your code. you have a `with ie` block, but you refer to `ie` inside the block 3 times.  just drop the use of the `with` block and use `ie.visible ..` and `ie.navigate ..`

Answer (score 0):

Typically you can access a node in 3 ways:

1. By using the getElementsByTagName() method
2. By looping through (traversing) the nodes tree.
3. By navigating the node tree, using the node relationships.

I was unable to achieve the first method but below are 4 examples of the latter 2 methods and a 5th method of parsing the string and extracting the required string using Split function.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim http As Object, xml As String            'Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://research.investors.com/services/AutoSuggest.asmx/GetQuoteResults?q=txn&limit=10", False
        .send
        xml = .responseText
    End With

    Dim doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    If Not doc.LoadXML(xml) Then
        Err.Raise doc.parseError.ErrorCode, , doc.parseError.reason
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Debug.Print "Method 1 " & doc.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(0).LastChild.Text
    Debug.Print "Method 2 " & doc.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(2).Text '<== IXMLDOMElement

    Dim node As IXMLDOMElement, node2 As IXMLDOMElement

    For Each node In doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes
        For Each node2 In node.ChildNodes
            If node2.nodeName = "Url" Then
                Debug.Print "Method 3 " & node2.Text
                Exit For
            End If
        Next node2
    Next node

    Dim m As IXMLDOMNodeList, i As Long
    Set m = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes

    For i = 0 To doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Length - 1

        Dim x As IXMLDOMElement
        Set x = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes(i)
        Dim xlen As Long, y As IXMLDOMElement, n As Long
        xlen = x.ChildNodes.Length
        Set y = x.FirstChild

        For n = 0 To xlen - 1
            If y.nodeName = "Url" Then
                Debug.Print "Method 4 " & y.Text
            End If
            Set y = y.NextSibling
        Next n

    Next i

    Debug.Print "Method 5 " & Split(Split(xml, "<Url>")(1), "</Url")(0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Any feedback on this?